# Networks - Bit Stuffing

Tags: computer-science

I have this question about networking regarding bit stuffing. I am slightly confused about the answer provided. Please help me understand it.

**QUestion:** When bit stuffing is used, is it possible for the loss, insertion, or modification of a
single bit to cause an error not detected by the checksum? If not, why not? If so, how?
Does the check sum length play a role here?

**Answer:** It is possible. If data is 01111110 -> 011111010 if the second 0 is lost due to
transmission error, 01111110 will received, which can be interpreted as end of frame.
The bits before the end of the frame will then be interpreted as the checksum. 
**If the
checksum is 4 bits, there is 1 chance in 24
that these random bits will be interpreted as a
valid checksum. The longer the checksum, the less likely that this mistake will happen**

I did not understand the bolded part. What does it mean that there is 1 in 24 chance that it will be interpreted as a valid checksum? I will be happy if someone could clarify it for me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short checksums will only help identify faulty transmission with a small number of bits wrong. 
For example:

-1 checksum bit + byte of data will detect correctly one bit wrong in the data but two bits wrong may cause checksum to be evaluates as correct.

-2 checksum bits (depending on the implementation) + byte of data can identify 2 faulty bits in any location of data.

-Once you reach 4 bits of checksum per byte (1/2 ratio) you can even correct the wrong bits in both checksum and the data (RAID arrays use this)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is still confusing to me. if I insert,or modify a bit, we said that the checksum cannot detect that. Can you explain in your own words as to how it is possible? The reason I am asking for your interpretation is because I see my self confused as I continue digging deep into the answer provided since the answer is confusing to begin with.

Comment: Insertions,deletions, or general changes to the length of a stream are handled on the protocol level (TCP/IP) so you don't have to worry about that usually though you might be doing something special that you do not have that guarantee. The part that you should be worried about is bits flipping values which can in certain instances evaluate to a "good" packet. If one checksum bit is present, then one bit change will evaluate to a bad checksum but two bits changing can change both the data and the checksum causing your byte to be evaluated as "correct"

Comment: Having multiple checksum bytes allows for a detection of more bits switching values and the checksum algo still correctly identifying the allowable limit of bad data. This is usually offset by the need to reduce traffic so checksums are usually small in size to minimize bloat but large enough to detect an acceptable level of data corruption with ~99.99% accuracy

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the necro response but I have the answer to this in case anyone stumbles upon this question when doing their homework :D

The "1 in 24" answer you provided is wrong. A checksum of length 4 actually has a 1 in 16 (2^4) chance of being valid. Such an event is clearly less likely with increasing checksum length as increasing the length of the checksum by one decreases the likelihood by half.